# Is there a way I can use css3 calc to place a dialog in the center of my screen?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use the following:

```
<div class="center">
  ...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.center{
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background:red;
    top:calc(50% - 50px/2);
    left:calc(50% - 50px/2);
}
```

However it seems like the div is positioned not in the center of the viewport but in the center of the div that encloses it.

How can I make it so the div is positioned in the center of the screen using calc ?

Comment: Is the parent's position `relative`?

Comment: Yes the parents position is relative. I really need a way to detach its position completely from that of the parent.

Comment: Why not `top:50%; margin-top:-50px`?

Comment: @Melina Why not just place it outside of the parent? Or is that not an option?

Comment: I cannot place it outside of the parent. I wish I could :-(

Comment: @Melina Unless you are able to remove position relative from the parent, or remove the child from the parent completely, it is not possible.. as the positioning will always be relative to the parent.

Comment: If you can't place it outside of the parent then why not remove it and add it into the flow with jQuery? Is this an option you can use?

Comment: I thought if I use the position fixed. Does that not position relative to the browser window?

Comment: Fixed position seems to do the trick but it will be fixed to the page even if you scroll. http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/48U9f/. It will also overlay over content so that is something to consider ==> http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/48U9f/1/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not use the `top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;` trick?

http://jsfiddle.net/3n1gm4/WpYHS/

html:

```
<div class="centered">
    <h1>Perfectly Centered</h1>
    <h3>This is centered top to bottom and left to right</h3>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.centered {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 50%; /* any width */
    height: 30%; /* any height */
    margin: auto;

    text-align: center;

    background: #deface;
}
```

Comment: With this solution, the `height` must be set.

Comment: While true, the example given had the width and height set so I offered a solution which should have a tad bit better support than the flex box

Comment: Yes, I think Safari on Windows is somehow behind. Just wanted to note that down.

Comment: My major concern was with the proliferation of IE 7, 8 and 9 which make up 15% of global usage still >_<. It is worth noting I did up vote your answer as it would be the ideal solution if we only had to worry about the most modern browsers.

Comment: Google dropped support for IE < 9 so do I. If they are supported by most websites, no admin will care about updates. But if suddenly all employees complain about issues, they have to update or use another browser.

Comment: While it makes sense for the creator of a competitor to not support older versions of their competitors software. I still have to follow the business rules set up by the company I work for.  Every time I think we can get away limited support for an aging browser, we get bug reports relating to it.

Comment: Yes, this is a topic that can be discussed a long time^^

Answer (score 4):

You can use new `display: flex`

### CSS

```
#overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}

.dialog {
    margin: auto;
    width: 280px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kelunik/enSkf/1/)**

### Browser Support

Firefox, Safari 6, IE 11 (maybe 10), Opera, Chrome

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use:

```
.center {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: red;
    top: calc(50% - 25px);
    left: calc(50% - 25px);
}
```

or:

```
.center {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: red;
    margin-top: -25px;
    margin-left: -25px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use:

```
.center {
    float: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: And it doesn't center horizontal.