# Best Way to Centre Dynamic Div in Middle of Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know this sort of thing has been asked a lot but I want to be able to centre a div in the middle of the page and have it always stay in the middle of the page no matter how wide or tall it gets.

I'm guessing that it would be best to use some javascript to work out how wide the element will be and then half that amount to take away from the margin.

To clear things up, this sort of thing:

```
.myDivHere {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    text-align: center;        
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;
    margin-left: -273px; /*half width set by js script*/
    margin-top: -132px; /*half height set by js script*/
}
```

I have set the width and height to be 20% as I want this div to be able to retain its size relative to the browser window (for mobile support and such). Any ideas?

Comment: Is there anything on your page beside this div?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19644101/is-there-a-way-i-can-use-css3-calc-to-place-a-dialog-in-the-center-of-my-screen/19645362#19645362

Comment: [How to center a div vertically and horizontally (modern method, without fixed size!)](http://www.dev-metal.com/center-div-vertically-horizontally-modern-method-without-fixed-size/)

Answer (score 4):

Unless I'm missing something you can forgo the JavaScript and use plain CSS:

```
div {
    position:absolute;
    background:red;
    width:20%;
    height:20%;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/eCT4M/)**

Comment: Beat me to it. Excellent answer, and exactly how it should be done. This question/ other answers exemplifies how quickly people give up on CSS and run to javascript to write arbitrary functions which end up making the code unnecessarily confusing and difficult to maintain

Comment: Absolute positioning isn't necessary unless the DOM can't be changed.

Comment: @ShawnErquhart - That makes absolutely no sense, and is simply wrong.Plus the OP was using absolute positioning to start with.

Comment: Fair enough, downvote removed. Absolute positioning is generally a liability, though. Hard to say if it's worth it without knowing the OP's code context.

Comment: @ShawnErquhart see my comment regarding abs. positioning on your post. it is not a liability any more than any other css property used incorrectly is

Comment: So if you want something in the absolute center of the page, you shouldn't use `position: absolute` lol ok.   Using absolute positioning for an entire layout is bad, but this is the exact type of situation you SHOULD use absolute

Answer (score 0):

In `jQuery` you can use [`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) and [`.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) methods as they returns computed width in pixels, not in percentage + you will need to listen window `resize` event. For example like this:

```
$(function() {
    function updateDivPosition() {
        var myWidth = $( '.myDivHere' ).width()
          , myHeight = $( '.myDivHere' ).height();
        $( '.myDivHere' ).css( { 
            marginLeft: -( parseInt( myWidth, 10 ) / 2 ) + 'px',
            marginTop: -( parseInt( myHeight, 10 ) / 2 ) + 'px'
        });
    }
    updateDivPosition(); // first time set correct position on onload
    $( window ).resize( updateDivPosition ); // update on window resize
});
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YwuAw/)

Answer (score 0):

[Here is you go.](http://jsfiddle.net/UFMP7/1/)

It should be noted that this answer is more about concepts than giving you the answer outright.

Now, you see the 'div#b' section of the CSS? To keep everything in the center, simply write a script that keeps the margin-top value -50% of the height. And that's it!

Example: 
(currently) height = 60, margin-top = -30px (changed for height = 100) height = 100, margin-top = -50px

```
div#a
{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-width:1px;
    border-style: solid;

    /* important stuff below */
    display: inline-block; 
}

div#b
{
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: red;

    /* important stuff below */
    position: relative;
    margin: -30px auto 0 auto;
    top: 50%;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a codepen:

[**Check it out.**](http://codepen.io/erquhart/pen/aJiKF)

Most of your styles aren't necessary, and javascript is definitely unnecessary. The key to vertical centering is `display: table`. It requires some nesting, so I altered your structure as well.

Comment: display: table is nice and certainly a good tool to know. But is better used in situations when the html REQUIRES container elements or several other elements grouped together. This problem could be solved using only one div

Comment: It's standard practice for vertical alignment. Removing any element from document flow just for vertical alignment should generally be used as a last resort unless you're dealing with some sort of modal.

Comment: absolute positioning does not remove the element from document flow, it keeps it relative to the nearest parent, that has a defined position (not static). only fixed positioning removes it from the document flow

Comment: further more, vertical alignment can be achieved in several ways and the best way is completely dependent on the situation. for instance, display: inline-block and vertical-align: middle may be more than enough to handle many situations

Comment: OP said alignment was to the entire page, so unless the page is empty, it's going to be removed from flow. That said, I agree that we can't really answer the question properly without context.

Comment: as many elements as needed can be added without removing it from flow... that particular element just needs to stay with the parent as the body

Comment: Not sure you're understanding what document flow is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning