# to make a div inside a div always in middle of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am making a responsive gallery page but got stuck. All i want is to make my `.gallery-container` in middle in any width. There's a gap in right side which is not equal to left side. Is there any  way to maintain the gap between left and right side equal so that the gallery div will be always in middle of the page in any width?

If there is, it will help me alot

[heres my code](https://jsfiddle.net/sus_hill/1mtcs757/7/)

It's complicated because i have given width to image and without giving width i cant display bigger image while going to a link a. So, all i need is to make the half of the space of right side to left side also. I now figure out that's the work of js. If you can then do help me.

```css
.sj-main-content-inner {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 300px;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.gallery-container {
    margin: 0;
}
ul {
    list-style: square outside;
    /* margin: 0 0 20px 20px; */
}
.gallery-list {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 25px;
    width: 360px;
    border: 0;
}
li.gallery-list.col-lg-3.col-md-3.col-sm-6.col-xs-12:hover .gallery-title {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
.gallery-title {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 30px;
    width: 302px;
    margin-left: -151px;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 20px 10px;
}

.gallery-title h3 {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: none;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

.sj-read-more {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
    position: relative;
}
.sj-read-more:after {
    content: '';
    width: 60px;
    height: 1px;
    background: #a4a4a5;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -30px;
    bottom: 0;
    transition: all ease-out 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all ease-out 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: all ease-out 0.3s;
}
.sj-read-more:hover, .sj-read-more:focus, .sj-read-more:active {
    color: #e45f4d;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.sj-read-more:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    bottom: 15px;
    color: #e45f4d;
    transition: all ease-out 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all ease-out 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: all ease-out 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="sj-main-container">
 <div class="sj-main-content">
     <div class="sj-main-content-inner">
        
        <h1>Foto Gallery</h1>
 <ul class="gallery-container">
                            <li class="gallery-list col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                  <br>
            <img src="http://rack.2.mshcdn.com/media/ZgkyMDE1LzA5LzEzLzNjL2dvb2dsZXRodW1iLmIyNGE0LmpwZwpwCXRodW1iCTk1MHg1MzQjCmUJanBn/63126c72/af4/google-thumb.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                     <div class="gallery-title">
                        
                        <h3 class="sj-event-title">About this album for visitor</h3>
                        <a class="sj-read-more" title="Your caption here" href="http://upper.dev/swiss-japon/suissejapon110216/?gallery=fotos">View More</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                      <li class="gallery-list col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                  <br>
            <img src="http://rack.2.mshcdn.com/media/ZgkyMDE1LzA5LzEzLzNjL2dvb2dsZXRodW1iLmIyNGE0LmpwZwpwCXRodW1iCTk1MHg1MzQjCmUJanBn/63126c72/af4/google-thumb.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                       <div class="gallery-title">
                        
                        <h3 class="sj-event-title">About this album for visitor</h3>
                        <a class="sj-read-more" title="Your caption here" href="<?php the_permalink();?>">View More</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="gallery-list col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                  <br>
            <img src="http://rack.2.mshcdn.com/media/ZgkyMDE1LzA5LzEzLzNjL2dvb2dsZXRodW1iLmIyNGE0LmpwZwpwCXRodW1iCTk1MHg1MzQjCmUJanBn/63126c72/af4/google-thumb.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                       <div class="gallery-title">
                        
                        <h3 class="sj-event-title">About this album for visitor</h3>
                        <a class="sj-read-more" title="Your caption here" href="<?php the_permalink();?>">View More</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="gallery-list col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                  <br>
            <img src="http://rack.2.mshcdn.com/media/ZgkyMDE1LzA5LzEzLzNjL2dvb2dsZXRodW1iLmIyNGE0LmpwZwpwCXRodW1iCTk1MHg1MzQjCmUJanBn/63126c72/af4/google-thumb.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                       <div class="gallery-title">
                        
                        <h3 class="sj-event-title">About this album for visitor</h3>
                        <a class="sj-read-more" title="Your caption here" href="<?php the_permalink();?>">View More</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="gallery-list col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                  <br>
            <img src="http://rack.2.mshcdn.com/media/ZgkyMDE1LzA5LzEzLzNjL2dvb2dsZXRodW1iLmIyNGE0LmpwZwpwCXRodW1iCTk1MHg1MzQjCmUJanBn/63126c72/af4/google-thumb.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                       <div class="gallery-title">
                        
                        <h3 class="sj-event-title">About this album for visitor</h3>
                        <a class="sj-read-more" title="Your caption here" href="<?php the_permalink();?>">View More</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                  </ul>
            
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691711/best-way-to-centre-dynamic-div-in-middle-of-page

Comment: @cst1992 Its kind of same but your's links does not help me

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
    .sj-main-content-inner {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 300px;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.gallery-container {
  max-width: 800px;
  height:100%;
  background: #000;
  margin:auto;
}
ul {
    list-style: square outside;
    /* margin: 0 0 20px 20px; */
}
.gallery-list {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 360px;
    margin:auto;
    border: 0;
}
li.gallery-list.col-lg-3.col-md-3.col-sm-6.col-xs-12:hover .gallery-title {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
.gallery-title {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 30px;
    width: 302px;
    margin-left: -151px;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 20px 10px;
}

.gallery-title h3 {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: none;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

.sj-read-more {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
    position: relative;
}
.sj-read-more:after {
    content: '';
    width: 60px;
    height: 1px;
    background: #a4a4a5;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -30px;
    bottom: 0;
    transition: all ease-out 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all ease-out 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: all ease-out 0.3s;
}
.sj-read-more:hover, .sj-read-more:focus, .sj-read-more:active {
    color: #e45f4d;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.sj-read-more:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    bottom: 15px;
    color: #e45f4d;
    transition: all ease-out 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all ease-out 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: all ease-out 0.3s;
}
```

Now for making it responsive play with the values in his code and add it just where your CSS ends. For reference use this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
     .gallery-container{
       width:500px;
       margin:auto;
    }
}
```

Whenever you have to position a body to the centre use this as a trick:

```
<selector>{
    width:<x>px;
    margin:auto;
}
```

You can specify the top and bottom margin using `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` below `margin:auto;` but once you use this you can not set margin-left or margin-right.(But then you won't be requiring margin let/right because you are positioning the div in centre).

Comment: thank you, but i didn't find any changes using code.

Comment: @SusHill i got the problem giveme a minute i will edit my answer

Comment: It's complicated because i have given **width**  to image and without giving width i cant display bigger image while going to a link `a`. So, all i need is to make the half of the space of right side to left side also. I now figure out that's the work of **js**.  If you can then do help me.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by using jquery

```
$(function() {
function updateDivPosition() {
var myWidth = $( '.gallery-title' ).width(), myHeight = $( '.gallery-title' ).height();
$( '.gallery-title' ).css( { 
marginLeft: -( parseInt( myWidth, 10 ) / 2 ) + 'px',
marginTop: -( parseInt( myHeight, 10 ) / 2 ) + 'px'
});
}
updateDivPosition(); // first time set correct position on onload
$( window ).resize( updateDivPosition ); // update on window resize
});
```